# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have already tried inserting the script tag in my index.html after the closing body tag.

I have also tried changing `myForm.addEventListener('submit', addRecord);` to `document.addEventListener('submit', addRecord);` and it just changed but still throws the same null error in the `if(nameInput.value === '' || jobInput.value === '')` of the addRecord function in my main.js

main.js

```
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
const jobInput = document.querySelector('#job');
const employeeList = document.querySelector('#employeeList');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', addRecord);

export function addRecord() {

    if(nameInput.value === '' || jobInput.value === '') {
        alert('Please complete all the fields.');
    } 
    else {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${nameInput.value} (${jobInput.value})`));
        employeeList.appendChild(li);
        nameInput.value = "";
        jobInput.value = "";
    }
}

export function clearFields() {
    nameInput.value = "";
    jobInput.value = "";
}
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { addRecord, clearFields } from './main.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
        <table className="main">
            <tr className="split">
              <td>
                <div className="left">
                  <form id="my-form">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
                      <input className="text" type="text" id="name" /><br /><br />
                      <label for="job">Job Detail:</label><br />
                      <input className="text" type="text" id="job" /><br /><br />
                      <input className="btn-add" type="submit" value="Add" onclick={addRecord()}/>
                      <input className="btn-clear" type="button" value="Clear" onclick={clearFields()} />
                  </form>  
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className="right">
                  <p>Employee List</p>
                  <ul className="employeeList" id="employeeList"></ul>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Also, this is already working as a simple web app. I just need to convert it into a react app

Comment: You're importing `addRecord` from `main.js`, so why not just use `onSubmit={addRecord}` in the form when the JSX is rendered?

Comment: Error is still the same when I added that in the form.

Comment: Then it would seem that you must have not removed the `addEventListener` part of the code when you made the change.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up a bit on [event handling in ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Answer (score 0):

In React you can use Formik to handle your form.

But if you really want to do like this you have to put your scripts in componentDidMount or useEffect, because you are selecting an element that is not rendered yet in dom so you get this error.